# FreeCodeCamp 37 Hour Flutter Course Notes not appearing issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, sqlite, dart

I'm new to stackoverflow and coding completely.

I'm working through FreeCodeCamp.org's 37-hour Flutter Course for beginners and have hit a road block at approx 21:46:23.
I cannot get anything that's input into 'New Note' to appear on the main 'Your Notes' view.
I've worked forward to 21:51:02 but still none of the notes appear when returning back to the main page.
Going back to 21:46:23, when I print to the debug console I am faced with the following:

```
I/flutter ( 9892): []
E/SQLiteLog( 9892): (1) table note has no column named is_sycned_with_cloud in "INSERT INTO note (user_id, text, is_sycned_with_cloud) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
```

Not really sure what to do but have been stuck here for a few days now and can't figure it out...
Code is as below...
I understand the problem could be in the code on another page/file so just ask if you'd like to see any of the code outside of whats below. Much appreciated all.

**new_note_view.dart**

```
import 'package:beginnerbeginning/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:beginnerbeginning/services/crud/notes_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewNoteView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewNoteView({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewNoteView> createState() => _NewNoteViewState();
}

class _NewNoteViewState extends State<NewNoteView> {
  DatabaseNote? _note;
  late final NotesService _notesService;
  late final TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _notesService = NotesService();
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _textControllerListener() async {
    final note = _note;
    if (note == null) {
      return;
    }
    final text = _textController.text;
    await _notesService.updateNote(
      note: note,
      text: text,
    );
  }

  void _setupTextControllerListener() {
    _textController.removeListener(_textControllerListener);
    _textController.addListener(_textControllerListener);
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> createNewNote() async {
    final existingNote = _note;
    if (existingNote != null) {
      return existingNote;
    }
    final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;
    final email = currentUser.email!;
    final owner = await _notesService.getUser(email: email);
    return await _notesService.createNote(owner: owner);
  }

  void _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty() {
    final note = _note;
    if (_textController.text.isEmpty && note != null) {
      _notesService.deleteNote(id: note.id);
    }
  }

  void _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty() async {
    final note = _note;
    final text = _textController.text;
    if (note != null && text.isNotEmpty) {
      await _notesService.updateNote(
        note: note,
        text: text,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty();
    _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty();
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        title: const Text(
          'New Note',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: createNewNote(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              _note = snapshot.data;
              _setupTextControllerListener();
              return TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Start typing your note...',
                ),
              );
            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**notes_view.dart**

```
import 'package:beginnerbeginning/constants/routes.dart';
import 'package:beginnerbeginning/enums/menu_action.dart';
import 'package:beginnerbeginning/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:beginnerbeginning/services/crud/notes_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NotesView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotesView({super.key});

  @override
  State<NotesView> createState() => _NotesViewState();
}

class _NotesViewState extends State<NotesView> {
  late final NotesService _notesService;
  String get userEmail => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.email!;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _notesService = NotesService();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            'Your notes',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(newNoteRoute);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            PopupMenuButton<MenuAction>(
              onSelected: (value) async {
                switch (value) {
                  case MenuAction.logout:
                    final shouldLogout = await showLogOutDialog(context);
                    if (shouldLogout) {
                      await AuthService.firebase().logOut();
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                        loginRoute,
                        (_) => false,
                      );
                    }
                }
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.white),
              itemBuilder: (context) {
                return const [
                  PopupMenuItem<MenuAction>(
                    value: MenuAction.logout,
                    child: Text('Log out'),
                  ),
                ];
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _notesService.getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.done:
                return StreamBuilder(
                  stream: _notesService.allNotes,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                      case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      case ConnectionState.active:
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          final allNotes = snapshot.data as List<DatabaseNote>;
                          print(allNotes);
                          return const Text('Got all the notes');
                        } else {
                          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                      default:
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  },
                );
              default:
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}

Future<bool> showLogOutDialog(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Sign out'),
        content: const Text('Are you sure you want to sign out?'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            },
            child: const Text('Cancel'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
            child: const Text('Log out'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ).then((value) => value ?? false);
}
```

**notes_service.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:beginnerbeginning/services/crud/crud_exceptions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' show join;

class NotesService {
  Database? _db;

  List<DatabaseNote> _notes = [];

  static final NotesService _shared = NotesService._sharedInstance();
  NotesService._sharedInstance() {
    _notesStreamController = StreamController<List<DatabaseNote>>.broadcast(
      onListen: () {
        _notesStreamController.sink.add(_notes);
      },
    );
  }
  factory NotesService() => _shared;

  late final StreamController<List<DatabaseNote>> _notesStreamController;

  Stream<List<DatabaseNote>> get allNotes => _notesStreamController.stream;

  Future<DatabaseUser> getOrCreateUser({required String email}) async {
    try {
      final user = await getUser(email: email);
      return user;
    } on CouldNotFindUser {
      final createdUser = await createUser(email: email);
      return createdUser;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _cacheNotes() async {
    final allNotes = await getAllNotes();
    _notes = allNotes.toList();
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> updateNote({
    required DatabaseNote note,
    required String text,
  }) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    // make sure note exists
    await getNote(id: note.id);

    // update DB
    final updatesCount = await db.update(noteTable, {
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedWithCloudColumn: 0,
    });

    if (updatesCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotUpdateNote();
    } else {
      final updatedNote = await getNote(id: note.id);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == updatedNote.id);
      _notes.add(updatedNote);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return updatedNote;
    }
  }

  Future<Iterable<DatabaseNote>> getAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final notes = await db.query(noteTable);

    return notes.map((noteRow) => DatabaseNote.fromRow(noteRow));
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> getNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final notes = await db.query(
      noteTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );

    if (notes.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindNote();
    } else {
      final note = DatabaseNote.fromRow(notes.first);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notes.add(note);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return note;
    }
  }

  Future<int> deleteAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final numberOfDeletions = await db.delete(noteTable);
    _notes = [];
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    return numberOfDeletions;
  }

  Future<void> deleteNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      noteTable,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
    if (deletedCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteNote();
    } else {
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseNote> createNote({required DatabaseUser owner}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    // make sure the owner exists in the database with the correct id
    final dbUser = await getUser(email: owner.email);
    if (dbUser != owner) {
      throw CouldNotFindUser();
    }

    const text = '';
    //create the note
    final noteId = await db.insert(noteTable, {
      userIdColumn: owner.id,
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedWithCloudColumn: 1,
    });

    final note = DatabaseNote(
      id: noteId,
      userId: owner.id,
      text: text,
      isSyncedWithCloud: true,
    );

    _notes.add(note);
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);

    return note;
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> getUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );

    if (results.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindUser();
    } else {
      return DatabaseUser.fromRow(results.first);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> createUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );
    if (results.isNotEmpty) {
      throw UserAlreadyExists();
    }

    final userId = await db.insert(userTable, {
      emailColumn: email.toLowerCase(),
    });

    return DatabaseUser(
      id: userId,
      email: email,
    );
  }

  Future<void> deleteUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      userTable,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );
    if (deletedCount != 1) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteUser();
    }
  }

  Database _getDatabaseOrThrow() {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
    } else {
      return db;
    }
  }

  Future<void> close() async {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
    } else {
      await db.close();
      _db = null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _ensureDbIsOpen() async {
    try {
      await open();
    } on DatabaseAlreadyOpenException {
      // empty
    }
  }

  Future<void> open() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      throw DatabaseAlreadyOpenException();
    }
    try {
      final docsPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final dbPath = join(docsPath.path, dbName);
      final db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
      _db = db;

      // create user table
      await db.execute(createUserTable);
      // create note table
      await db.execute(createNoteTable);
      await _cacheNotes();
    } on MissingPlatformDirectoryException {
      throw UnableToGetDocumentsDirectory();
    }
  }
}

@immutable
class DatabaseUser {
  final int id;
  final String email;
  const DatabaseUser({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
  });

  DatabaseUser.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        email = map[emailColumn] as String;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Person, ID = $id, email = $email';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseUser other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

class DatabaseNote {
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String text;
  final bool isSyncedWithCloud;

  DatabaseNote({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.text,
    required this.isSyncedWithCloud,
  });

  DatabaseNote.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        userId = map[userIdColumn] as int,
        text = map[textColumn] as String,
        isSyncedWithCloud =
            (map[isSyncedWithCloudColumn] as int) == 1 ? true : false;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'Note, ID = $id, userId = $userId, isSyncedWithCloud = $isSyncedWithCloud, text = $text';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseNote other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

const dbName = 'notes.db';
const noteTable = 'note';
const userTable = 'user';
const idColumn = 'id';
const emailColumn = 'email';
const userIdColumn = 'user_id';
const textColumn = 'text';
const isSyncedWithCloudColumn = 'is_sycned_with_cloud';
const createUserTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
        "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "email" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
      );''';
const createNoteTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "note" (
        "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "user_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "text"  TEXT,
        "is_synced_with_cloud"  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        FOREIGN KEY("user_id") REFERENCES "user"("id"),
        PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
      );''';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Possible typo in ```is_sycned_with_cloud``` in your definition ```const isSyncedWithCloudColumn = 'is_sycned_with_cloud';``` You sure it's not ```is_synced_with_cloud```?

Comment: Oh wow... that solved the problem haha! I can't believe I didn't pick that up it was literally printing it to me in the debug console. Thank you so much ewokx, much appreciated!